# Calculating yearly standard deviation, given monthly returns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation

I have a function to calculate monthly returns:

```
def monthlyreturns(df):
    first = df.resample('M').first().to_period('M')
    last = df.resample('M').last().to_period('M')
    return ((last-first)/first) * 100
```

and a resulting df from monthlyreturns(stocks):

```
           FOX     FOXA     MMM
Date
2012-01    5.4     3.2      -.08
2012-02    .07     1.2      -.62
...
2017-08    -.2     -4.2     2.3
```

My question is - how can I calculate the standard deviation for ea year? My expected output would be to keep the df in the same format (with stocks in columns, and date as index) , but calculate the yearly standard deviation, given monthly returns (so there should be about 7 values for ea stock)

So far I have tried:

```
sd = pd.DataFrame()
x = -13
y = -1
for date in reversed(periods):                     #where periods is ea year
    sd[date] = np.std(monthly_returns.iloc[x:y])      
x -= 12
y -= 12
if x < -72:
    break
```

This works - but the dates and columns are swapped , and was wondering if there was a cleaner code to do this

Comment: When you apply a loop to a pandas object, in 99% of cases you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I knew there a 1 liner like this , I did not know about the index.year part - thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
monthly_returns.groupby(monthly_returns.index.year).std()
```

For your example:

```
#           FOX      FOXA       MMM
#2012  3.768879  1.414214  0.381838
#2017       NaN       NaN       NaN
```